# Technologies used for dynamic messaging when data in changed in the database

Tags: java, android, iphone, web-services, web

I would like to know what technology to use in order to send notifications/messages to a multiple device instantly when any changes are made in the users account in the database which will be there in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/what-is-aws/). AWS is a language and operating system agnostic platform and it is really easy to use. As it is cloud based they are highly available, scalable and secure.

You could use:

- [Amazon Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS)](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/)  for notifications.
- [Amazon Simple Queue Service (Amazon SQS)](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) for messaging.
- [Amazon Simple Email Service (Amazon SES)](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) for emails.

You could also consider using databases services such as [Amazon DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) which is a great is a fully managed NoSQL database service.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Push Notification? I am using Urban Airship for sending push notification, please refer the document [here](https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Home).